# Global variables pop-up as `undefined` when hovering in subscribe() during debugging on chrome DevTools

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, debugging, observable, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on Angular projects where more than 100 variables are declared as global. When I try to debug the component in google chrome Dev Tool, global variables inside any subscribe() observable shown as `undefined`, but they have a value.
If I hover the variable, which is set outside any subscribe, they shows correct value. I faced same issue in Firefox also, but setting, 'Show variable variable' as checked. But I couldn't fix that in chrome. Is there any way to fix the issue?

I used log to console the value, it shows the correct value, but during the debugging, it showing as `undefined`

[!Firefox - option to select *Show original variables*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8jUF.png)

Sample videos

[Video showing debugging inside subscribe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1280J1Wh2Pir2QzEqAX0RntF-WH2cr49i/view?usp=sharing)

[Video showing variable value while debugging](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRoAqTL0CfSHaQ63Z0-bkiQiPezz9qrX/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Chrome version]